# How to add a WAR from a remote repository to an EAR with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, war, ear

Just want to include a war file (from my remote repo) while packaging a EAR with gradle.
But war file is available inside my central repository.

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ':XXX-XXX-war', configuration:'archives')
}
```

Want to add something like below

```
dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ':https://XXX.......', configuration:'archives')
}
```

where `https://XXX.......` is my repository url.Is it possible to do it in this way.

Am using gradle 4.10

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, did you find a solution?